# Why is Owin sometimes dropping Content-Encoding?

Tags: c#, gzip, response, owin, content-encoding

[Edit] **The problem seems to be something on our machines that is intercepting HTML sent via port 8888 -- changing the port number appears to fix things.  What is running on port 8888 that might do this is still a mystery. **

I have the oddest bug in my Owin handler returning an HTML response.  I've stripped it down to just this:

```
internal static Task WebUIHandler(IOwinRequest request, IOwinResponse response)
{
    response.ContentType = "text/html";
    var html = ... build an HTML string ...;
    response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
    response.Write(GZip.CompressUTF8(html));
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

The `GZip.CompressUTF8` call is to a utility method compressing the `html` string into a byte array (yes, I know this can be done with streams, but that isn't the point here).

When I run this app, the pages it serves appear to be uncompressed (i.e., in plaintext, NOT gzipped) and the `Content-Encoding` header is absent (I've examined this in Fiddler4, Chrome, and Firefox).

*However*, if I place a breakpoint on the `return` statement and let the application just sit for a few seconds before continuing, then the response *is* gzipped and the `Content-Encoding` header *is* included.  But only if I let it set on the breakpoint for a few seconds: if I continue too quickly, no gzip for me.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?  I am mystified.

[Edit: as requested, the whole "pipeline":]

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
...
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var startOptions = new StartOptions();
    startOptions.Urls.Add(...url...);
    using (WebApp.Start(startOptions, AppBuilderAction)) {
        ...
    }
}
...
static void AppBuilderAction(IAppBuilder app) {
    var router = new Router();
    router.Add("/", WebUIHandler); // See above.
    ...
    app.Run(router.OwinHandler);
}
...
[Router method]
public Task OwinHandler(IOwinContext context) {
    var request = context.Request;
    var response = context.Response;
    ... find a handler matching request.Path.Value ...
    return handler(request, response);
}
```

and that's it.  Nothing else should get in the way, unless I've misunderstood the Owin scheme.

Comment: Which implementation of OWIN are you using?

Comment: I'm linking against Microsoft.Owin and Microsoft.Owin.Hosting,  3.0.1.0.

Comment: In this example you are writing to the `response` - can you show the whole pipeline?

Comment: @Kamo, I've just edited the question to include the details you requested.  As you can see, this is about as simple as you can get.

Comment: I should point out that this weird un-gzipping behaviour does not happen when the response content-type is "application/json", but it does happen when the response content-type is "text/html".

Comment: Are you sending `Accept-Encoding` header with your request?

Comment: Yes, the client is sending `Accept-Encoding` with plain `gzip` in the value list.  The two mysteries here are (1) what is un-gzipping my content for me without my asking and (2) why does it not do that if I hold a breakpoint there for a few seconds?

Comment: Regarding your edit: have you got a virus scanner running?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 apparently, but I can't find any reference to it using port 8888, the one I'm using internally.